# How to get protocol from remote site nodejs

Tags: node.js

I would like to fetch protocol from remote site in nodejs. How can I do it?
For example I have some time sample.com. I would like to understand is this site support https or other protocol.

Comment: Wanted to know same thing today, 4 years after your question, and still no answer. I'll bet there's a way though.